# When do offline messages come through in ejabberd?

Tags: ios, xmpp, ejabberd, xmppframework

I'm using the XMPPFramework, bridging from Swift, and when I successfully connect and authenticate, the offline messages are not coming through. They sit in the ejabberd interface as "offline messages". I thought this would empty out once I authenticate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to send an online presence once you're authenticated.

```
var presence = XMPPPresence()
Static.xmppStream!.sendElement(presence)
```